# Explain this DB syntax 'SUM(CAST(AVG_CLAIM_PAID AS NUMERIC(18,2))) AVG_CLAIM_PAID' in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

I saw

```
SUM(CAST(AVG_CLAIM_PAID AS NUMERIC(18,2))) AVG_CLAIM_PAID
```

this syntax in `stored procedure`.Please explain clearly above DB Syntax.

Comment: As clear as your question?

Comment: The SQL in your title is different to the SQL in your question...

Comment: [ISNULL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), [SUM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql), [CAST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql)

Comment: [`numeric`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: I post wrong question initially. Now are you understanding clearly?-@Diado

Comment: I post wrong question initially. Now are you understanding clearly? -@MJH

Answer (score 0):

This is your condition :

```
(Category = @Category or isnull(@Category,'')='')
```

This will return data based on `Category` (what you have in `@Category`), if the `@Category` has no value or `null` then it will rerun all categories.

So, i would rewrite it with pure Boolean logic :

```
(Category = @Category OR @Category IS NULL)
```

**NOTE :** This answers the original question before edit.

Answer (score 0):

`AVG_CLAIM_PAID` can be the field name in table

That field datatype is not numeric like Int, Float, bigint so using `CAST()` is is converted into `NUMERIC(18,2)`

`NUMERIC(18)` to convert field value in numeric, while `2` is for decimal point

Example :

```
declare @var1  nvarchar(10)
set @var1 = '50.2545'
SELECT CAST(@var1 AS NUMERIC(18,2))
--output will be : 50.25 as Number
```

After that using `SUM()` it is calculating sum for all records in that table.